# Using rvm with a standalone ruby script

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have rvm installed on a Mac OS X 10.6 system with the system ruby and 1.9.1. I also have this basic ruby script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'curb-fu'
```

I need the script to use the system ruby regardless of what rvm's using at any given time; I'm assuming that I've got *that* right, at least.

I've switched to the system ruby (`rvm use system`) and then installed the gem (`gem install curb-fu`). If I run irb and type `require 'curb-fu'`, it works. However, running that script with `./myscript.rb` fails:

```
/Users/me/bin/podcast_notify.rb:6:in `require': no such file to load -- curb-fu (LoadError)
from /Users/me/bin/podcast_notify.rb:6
```

What's going wrong here? How do I install curb-fu so that it's always available to this script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -rubygems
require 'curb-fu'
```

Also, maybe you should use `sudo gem install` if you're back in system ruby land.

Comment: Thanks - I can't believe I forgot to require rubygems *again*…

Even with `sudo gem install`, though, it only works when the system ruby has been selected with rvm: I get `dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_str_new_cstr` otherwise...

Comment: If you have further questions about RVM, there are people willing to help 24/7 in the #rvm channel on freenode: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm.

Answer (score 3):

You need to require rubygems explicitely As Konstantin said.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby 

require "rubygems"
require "curb-fu"
```

Also, better to ask such questions in #rvm on irc.freenode.net